# Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined

Tags: routes, angular

I'm using angular2 RC.1 in my AppComponent i have two routes one for login(as default) and second for home(where i have routerLink for my pages)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '../app/appComponent.html',
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Toasty, SlimLoadingBar]

})
@Routes([
    {path: '/', component: loginComponent}
     ,{path: '/home', component: homeComponent}
])
```

when the login is correct I navigate to Home from loginComponent.ts

```
this._router.navigate(['/home']);
```

in loading project I get this error

```
: TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined
    platform-browser.umd.js:962EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefinedBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:962BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ platform-browser.umd.js:972ExceptionHandler.call @ core.umd.js:3696(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:8987ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ core.umd.js:6075ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ core.umd.js:6106NgZone.run @ core.umd.js:6330ApplicationRef_.run @ core.umd.js:8976coreLoadAndBootstrap @ core.umd.js:8786bootstrap @ platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js:469(anonymous function) @ sectionsTemplate.component.ts:17(anonymous function) @ sectionsTemplate.component.ts:209(anonymous function) @ sectionsTemplate.component.ts:209__exec @ system.src.js:1510entry.execute @ system.src.js:3926linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:3252getModule @ system.src.js:3220(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3256require @ system.src.js:3893(anonymous function) @ home.component.ts:17(anonymous function) @ home.component.ts:49(anonymous function) @ home.component.ts:49__exec @ system.src.js:1510entry.execute @ system.src.js:3926linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:3252getModule @ system.src.js:3220(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3256require @ system.src.js:3893(anonymous function) @ app.component.ts:9(anonymous function) @ app.component.ts:36(anonymous function) @ app.component.ts:36__exec @ system.src.js:1510entry.execute @ system.src.js:3926linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:3252getModule @ system.src.js:3220(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3256require @ system.src.js:3893(anonymous function) @ main.ts:2(anonymous function) @ main.ts:15(anonymous function) @ main.ts:15__exec @ system.src.js:1510entry.execute @ system.src.js:3926linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:3252link @ system.src.js:3095execute @ system.src.js:3432doDynamicExecute @ system.src.js:798link @ system.src.js:1000doLink @ system.src.js:652updateLinkSetOnLoad @ system.src.js:700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:512ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
    platform-browser.umd.js:962STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:962ExceptionHandler.call @ core.umd.js:3698(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:8987ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ core.umd.js:6075ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ core.umd.js:6106NgZone.run @ core.umd.js:6330ApplicationRef_.run @ core.umd.js:8976coreLoadAndBootstrap @ core.umd.js:8786bootstrap @ platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js:469(anonymous function) @ sectionsTemplate.component.ts:17(anonymous function) @ sectionsTemplate.component.ts:209(anonymous function) @ sectionsTemplate.component.ts:209__exec @ system.src.js:1510entry.execute @ system.src.js:3926linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:3252getModule @ system.src.js:3220(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3256require @ system.src.js:3893(anonymous function) @ home.component.ts:17(anonymous function) @ home.component.ts:49(anonymous function) @ home.component.ts:49__exec @ system.src.js:1510entry.execute @ system.src.js:3926linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:3252getModule @ system.src.js:3220(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3256require @ system.src.js:3893(anonymous function) @ app.component.ts:9(anonymous function) @ app.component.ts:36(anonymous function) @ app.component.ts:36__exec @ system.src.js:1510entry.execute @ system.src.js:3926linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:3252getModule @ system.src.js:3220(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3256require @ system.src.js:3893(anonymous function) @ main.ts:2(anonymous function) @ main.ts:15(anonymous function) @ main.ts:15__exec @ system.src.js:1510entry.execute @ system.src.js:3926linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:3252link @ system.src.js:3095execute @ system.src.js:3432doDynamicExecute @ system.src.js:798link @ system.src.js:1000doLink @ system.src.js:652updateLinkSetOnLoad @ system.src.js:700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:512ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
    platform-browser.umd.js:962TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined
        at ReflectionCapabilities.annotations (core.umd.js:4124)
        at Reflector.annotations (core.umd.js:3956)
        at DirectiveResolver.resolve (compiler.umd.js:10564)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (compiler.umd.js:10875)
        at RuntimeCompiler.resolveComponent (compiler.umd.js:12977)
        at eval (core.umd.js:8789)
        at eval (core.umd.js:8978)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:323)
        at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (core.umd.js:6075)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:322)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:962ExceptionHandler.call @ core.umd.js:3699(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:8987ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ core.umd.js:6075ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ core.umd.js:6106NgZone.run @ core.umd.js:6330ApplicationRef_.run @ core.umd.js:8976coreLoadAndBootstrap @ core.umd.js:8786bootstrap @ platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js:469(anonymous function) @ sectionsTemplate.component.ts:17(anonymous function) @ sectionsTemplate.component.ts:209(anonymous function) @ sectionsTemplate.component.ts:209__exec @ system.src.js:1510entry.execute @ system.src.js:3926linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:3252getModule @ system.src.js:3220(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3256require @ system.src.js:3893(anonymous function) @ home.component.ts:17(anonymous function) @ home.component.ts:49(anonymous function) @ home.component.ts:49__exec @ system.src.js:1510entry.execute @ system.src.js:3926linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:3252getModule @ system.src.js:3220(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3256require @ system.src.js:3893(anonymous function) @ app.component.ts:9(anonymous function) @ app.component.ts:36(anonymous function) @ app.component.ts:36__exec @ system.src.js:1510entry.execute @ system.src.js:3926linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:3252getModule @ system.src.js:3220(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3256require @ system.src.js:3893(anonymous function) @ main.ts:2(anonymous function) @ main.ts:15(anonymous function) @ main.ts:15__exec @ system.src.js:1510entry.execute @ system.src.js:3926linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:3252link @ system.src.js:3095execute @ system.src.js:3432doDynamicExecute @ system.src.js:798link @ system.src.js:1000doLink @ system.src.js:652updateLinkSetOnLoad @ system.src.js:700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:512ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
    (index):18 Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined(…)
```

when I make homeCoponent in comment I get my view I get as error this : `Cannot find default outlet` but I get my login view

```
//{path: '/home', component: homeComponent}
```

+
in homeComponent i have

```
@Routes([
    {path: '/op1', component: ComponentOne},
    {path: '/op2', component: addUserComponentTwo}
    )]
```

I adding `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` both in homeCompnent and appComponet

Comment: I don't know if the part in my updated answer already fixes your issue but you should fix this anyway.

Comment: How does the template of your `AppComponent` look like?

Comment: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: Is the `AppComponent` shown if you remove `<router-outlet>` and `@Routes()`?

Comment: yes it shown correctly

Comment: and you know about  Cannot find default outlet

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in a Plunker? (use this as template https://plnkr.co/edit/cbEpkV7Ge7aT11CnjFuh?p=preview, don't add `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` anywhere because it's already in `main.ts`)

Comment: you follow what I'm doing ?  I dont know how plunker work !

Comment: I don't know. I tried to reproduce your example in the Plunker and it's working there. I need you to point out what you do differently.

Answer (score 1):

**update**

Change the order of the routes so that the more specific routes come first:

```
@Routes([
    {path: '/home', component: homeComponent}
    {path: '/', component: loginComponent},
])
```

This is a known issue in the RC.1 router and should be fixed.

**original**

Either `my-app` doesn't match an element inside `<body>` like

```
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>
```

or the component in `bootstrap(AppComponent)` does not exist or is not properly imported.

Comment: despite i thange order I get always the some error 
I want to add some things (my Typescript files my past them from another project this is can cause an error you said not properly imported)

Comment: As far as I know the error "Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined" is caused by what I wrote in my original answer.